# Create Regex search instance for each item in a string

Tags: c#, regex

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
```

N00b here,
How would I make a search instance for each line of text in `string1`? I want to search `string2` in it's entirety to see if it contains that 1 line of text in `string1's` search instance for every item in the `string2`. Both `string1` and `string2` have lines of text that are separated by a `'\n'`. Is there some obvious way to do this? Someone suggested a RegEx, but how would I incorporate a RegEx to find and print out matches in `string2` for each item in `string1`.. There is more than a few instances in `string2` that relate to the single item in `string1`.

A few in `string1`:
Part_numbers
1017FOO
1121BAR
*etc...*

A few in `string2`:
SUPERCOLA A 51661017FOOAINDO
DASUDAMA C 89891121BARBLO5W
*etc...*

Probably going to figure this out later, but I want them to be formatted like this, just for FYI

1017FOO matched:
SUPERCOLA A 51661017FOOAINDO
+another one that 1017FOO matched+
*etc...*
Thanks in advance!
Looking for pointers in the right direction, on what methods I should be using

Comment: What have you tried so far? P.S. The first, and most obvious, way is perhaps using the properties of the string method (i.e. `String.IndexOf`). I would **strongly** recommend that you show some code.

Comment: -1 for quality of the question - no code, very bad sample values, random unrelated text like "Probably going to figure this out later".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements as written don't require Regular Expressions so I didn't use them. You should be able to incorporate them pretty easily if you need to...

```
string partNumbers = @"1017Foo
1121BAR
SomethingElse";
string searchText = @"SUPERCOLA A 51661017FOOAINDO
DASUDAMA C 89891121BARBLO5W";

string[] searchTerms = partNumbers.Split('\n');
string[] searchedLines = searchText.Split('\n');

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

foreach(string searchTerm in searchTerms){
    int matchCount = 0;

    output.AppendLine(string.Format("For term: {0}", searchTerm.Trim()));
    foreach(string searchedLine in searchedLines){
        if(searchedLine.Trim().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.Trim().ToLower())){
            output.AppendLine(searchedLine.Trim());
            matchCount++;
        }
    }

    if(matchCount == 0){
        output.AppendLine("There was no match");
    }

    output.AppendLine("== End of search ==");
}

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```